# Operator on the space of square summable sequences

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, inequality

We define an operator $T:\mathcal{l}^2(\mathbb{Z})\rightarrow\mathcal{l}^2(\mathbb{Z})$ where $\mathcal{l}^2(\mathbb{Z})$ is the Hilbert space of square summable functions, such that for $\psi\in\mathcal{l}^2(\mathbb{Z})$, $$(T\psi)(n)=\psi(n-1)+\psi(n+1)-2\psi(n).$$ We also define $s$ and $s^\dagger$ which are the left shift and right shift operators, i.e., $(s\psi)(n)=\psi(n-1)$. We define the norm the usual way on this space, i.e. the sum over the integers of the sequence multiplied by its conjugate.

To show $T$ is a bounded operator, we calculate $$\|T\psi\|\leq\|s\psi\|+\|s^{\dagger}\psi\|-2\|\operatorname{id}\psi\|=\|\psi\|+\|\psi\|-2\|\psi\|=0.$$ But then $T$ must be zero? I was wondering if I was missing something, or if $T$ really is simply the zero operator.

Comment: Wouldnt it be $||T\psi|| \leq  4 ||\psi||$ ?

Comment: Great, thank you! I see where I went wrong.